# Retrieve Umbraco Tags datatype field in a LINQ query

Tags: linq, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to insert the values of an Umbraco.Tags datatype field into my razor output for each record from a LINQ query of my content.  I'm having trouble finding the right syntax.  I realize it should be a string array but everything I have tried fails.

In the page for the individual content I have been able to use the following where the content field is name "Tags".

```
var tags = CurrentPage.Tags;
```

The LINQ query is complex, but I am simply trying to add the tags to the output so that I can search inside the page for specific records on the client side. I have removed most of the query to make it easier to read.

```
var products = Model.Content.Site().Descendants<PenList>().First().Children("penProduct")
                    .Where(x => x.IsVisible())
                    .OfType<PenProduct>()
                    .Select(x => new ProductSearchResultItem() {
                    FilterText = x.ProductName + " " + x.ProductDescription.ToString() + " " + x.CompanyName.NullSafeToString() + " " + x.ProductType.ToString() 
                            + " " + (x.Parent.GetProperty("tags") != null ? x.Parent.GetProperty("tags").Value : string.Empty)})
```

I have also tried just getting x.Tags or x.GetProperty("tags") with no success.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Timothy, I just wanted to flag that using .Descendants in that manner (i.e. off the back of Site(), is going to be exceptionally inefficient. The use of Descendants should be limited as much as possible as it is considered bad practice due to potential performance and memory issues.

Comment: I'll see if there is a way I can rework it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Is the tags property on the penProduct doc type or the penList?  It looks like you're looking for it on the penList.

But I would think it would behave like any other string.  I don't normally use typed modals, but to get a list of the tag values in my views I use:

```
var tags = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("tags", "").Split(',');
```

Comment: It is looking at penProduct: Descendants<PenList>().First().Children("penProduct").  I can see what you are saying though.   I have tried to get the property on the x which should be the product itself but I get a LINQ error like it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is actually a string array I had to use the following code to get the property as a string array generic otherwise it would return the text of the type "System.String[]".

```
x.GetPropertyValue<string[]>("tags")
```